# How to not let django create django_migrations table

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

After the first creation of my database I don't want to change it,I won't need to `makemigrations` or to `migrate` from my django project, and I don't want Django to create `django_migrations` table, How I could do that?

I've already added `managed = False` in all my models, but the `django_migrations` is added in the database

Answer (score 0):

You can selectively disable migration for one or more Django Models by setting `managed = False` in Django Model Meta options. [From the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/options/#managed):

> Defaults to True, meaning Django will create the appropriate database
> tables in migrate or as part of migrations and remove them as part of
> a flush management command. That is, Django manages the database
> tables’ lifecycles.
>
> If False, no database table creation, modification, or deletion
> operations will be performed for this model. This is useful if the
> model represents an existing table or a database view that has been
> created by some other means. This is the only difference when
> managed=False. All other aspects of model handling are exactly the
> same as normal. This includes

Example, [from the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/models/#differences-between-proxy-inheritance-and-unmanaged-models:%7E:text=table%20columns%2C%20use-,Meta.managed%3DFalse,-.%20That%20option%20is:%7E:text=abstract%20%3D%20True-,managed,-%3D%20False%0A%0Aclass):

```py
class Unmanaged(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        managed = False
```

Comment: I've already done that, but the django_migrations table is added in the database